# Текст в блоках - HTML, CSS

Tags: css3, html5, html, text, icon

Привет, нужно поместить текст и иконки в блок, а когда начинаешь их прописывать блок смещается ниже нужного уровня. Что делать?

```css
.container{
    width: 1143px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.title_process{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
 
.block{
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
 
.blue{
    height: 263px;
    width: 262px;
    background-color: #4eb2f7;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 32px;
}
 
.violet{
    height: 263px;
    width: 262px;
    background-color: #c049f8;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 32px;
}
 
.yellow{
    height: 263px;
    width: 262px;
    background-color: #f3ee23;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 32px;
}
 
.red{
    height: 263px;
    width: 262px;
    background-color: #f74770;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<section id="process">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title_process">
                <h1><span>Working</span> Process</h1>
                <div class="titles_first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, eveniet.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="blue">
                    
                </div>  
                <div class="violet">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="yellow">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="red">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите маржин у кнопки или у текста/дайте паддинг нижний блоку самому.

Comment: Так маржина у кнопки и нет

Comment: паддинг блоку нижний тогда. расширьте его.у Вас стоит высота фиксированная. потому и едет

Answer (score 1):

Установите для дочерних блоков vertical-align:top или middle (по ситуации)

```css
.container{
    width: 1143px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.title_process{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
 
.block{
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
 
.block__item{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:263px;
    height:263px;
    margin-right:32px;
}
.blue{
    background-color: #4eb2f7;
}
 
.violet{
    background-color: #c049f8;
}
 
.yellow{
    background-color: #f3ee23;
}
 
.red{
    background-color: #f74770;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="process">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title_process">
                <h1><span>Working</span> Process</h1>
                <div class="titles_first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, eveniet.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block__item blue">
                    <span>Лорем ипсум долор</span>
                </div>  
                <div class="block__item violet">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="block__item yellow">
                    <h2>Лорем ипсум долор</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="block__item red">
                    <span>Лорем ипсум долор</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```